# How long should I wait before painting a concrete patch?

Tags: painting

How long do I have to wait to paint a polymer concrete repair such as Sakrete Top N Bond with Behr one part epoxy concrete paint? The repair is indoor and temp. is about 60 degrees F.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.sakrete.com/uploads/downloads/Sakrete%20Top%20N%20Bond%20Tech%20Data%204-10.pdf) (PDF), it reaches foot traffic compressive strength within one day and you can drive vehicles over it within three days, but doens't reach full compressive strength until 28 days. The PROPER answer here is probably 28 days, which is pretty consistent for any concrete products.

You can probably safely paint it within three days, but I'd be worried that concrete wouldn't reach full compressive strength or that the bond with the underlying concrete would be affected by moisture not having any path out.

Comment: +1, also this is the scenario where priming the surface is a very good idea.