# How long should I let a concrete repair dry before laying carpet?

Tags: concrete, basement, flooring, carpet

I recently had to repair a very small area (roughly a 2 ft wide x 1 ft rectangle) of my basement concrete floor after a water pipe repair. This area will have carpet installed over the concrete. The rest of the floor is completely dry and in good condition.

What is a minimum wait time I should wait before beginning pad and carpet installation?

Comment: (*'dry'* in) 24h? If you're going to use glue, then anywhere from a month to 3m (to *cure* and completely *set*). And that's after using w/e the bottle of glue says to do to concrete that only been cured for X amount of time. - Also, you're not supposed to let it 'dry' before it *sets*. For the first three days (week?) you are wetting it, then covering it back up with plastic sheet, so that it can cure more before it dries out.

Comment: @Mazura that's a much better answer than comment...

Comment: [How long should I wait before painting a concrete patch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11194/how-long-should-i-wait-before-painting-a-concrete-patch)

Comment: [How long to let a concrete walkway cure](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/164992/how-long-to-let-a-concrete-walkway-cure)

Comment: First one's got the "28" days but paint instead of glue, and the second talks about using plastic. Everything is a dupe @FreeMan ... This one's my fav, but only mildly related : [How long will Concrete bond together when poured over multiple days?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/70010/how-long-will-concrete-bond-together-when-poured-over-multiple-days)

Comment: That all being said.... if it's dry to the touch there isn't really any reason you can't just carpet it. Nobody ever actually keeps it wet like you're supposed to. I mean, unless you think it's too moist down there, and the padding will grow mold under it in the ~3? days it should take at most to 'dry'. - If that isn't the case then there's a moisture issue down there that you should be dealing with anyway.

Comment: If it's a dupe, @Mazura, _please_ VtC as such and pick the one you feel is the most appropriate...

Answer (score 0):

You suppose to keep it moist for a week to prevent stress induced cracks.

After that another week or more to let it dry.

The dry time will depend on the temperature.